# How to make a document like Github Graphql DOC?

Tags: document

I want to build a API document like this:
https://developer.github.com/v4/
But I don't know-how.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [APIDOC](https://apidocjs.com/) to make api documentation.